# GetWindowRect() returns wrong coordinates

Tags: python, pyautogui

**code**

```
import cv2
import pyautogui as pg
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time
import ctypes
import win32gui

def ScreenShot():
    hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, '小算盤') 
    print(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
    x, y, x1, y1 = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd) 
    time.sleep(1)
    im = pg.screenshot(region=(x,y, x1-x,y1-y))
    im.show()

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32 
user32.SetProcessDPIAware()
ScreenShot()
```

give me rusult like this:[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hRdC.png)

screenshot area is larger than application window size
and also left and top coordinates are wrong.

how can I fix it?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect): ... In Windows Vista and later, the Window Rect now includes the area occupied by the drop shadow... Probably that's why.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer thanks you for answer!